# Function not returning object for .then to work with - but able to console.log the object, and am explicitly returning it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, return, fetch

please can someone help shed some light as to why this .then is not taking the return value of the function call before it? This was working before I deployed to heroku, and I have a feeling its to do with eager loading, but I don't really know.

Basically the problem is: handleSubmit on registration calls on signup function, which is meant to return a user object, but .then isn't fed a return value from the signup function and errors: cannot read propery .then of undefined. So my handeSubmit is failing for trying to register to the app.

The signup method itself functions correctly (user is added to backend [Rails], JWT is provided and set in local storage in browser, and user object is rendered as JSON from API and succesfully console logged).

The handleSubmit looks like this:

```
      e.preventDefault();
      API.signup({ username, password })
         .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            props.setUser(user);
            history.push("/home");
         })
         .catch(errors => {
            setErrors(errors[errors]);
            console.error(errors);
         });
   };
```

The signup function looks like this:

```
const signup = userDetails => {
  fetch(SIGNUP_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ user: userDetails })
  })
  .then(jsonify)
  .then(data => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
    console.log(data.user)
    return data.user
  })
};
```

Interestingly my login function, which is identical to signup (even identical handleSubmit) aside from hitting a different endpoint on my API, works absolutely fine.

It's not a CORS issue I'm pretty sure otherwise login wouldn't work either. Thanks for any advice on how to debug this. I can provide back and frontend code on request.

Comment: in your signup function add return before fetch

Comment: wow that was quick. Thank you for pointing this out. Do you know why this issue only appeared after deployment to Heroku? On localhost this never happened

Comment: I m not sure but if i had to guess maybe in your development environment you didn't use the`{}` in your arrow function

Comment: I did, but ah well it works now and that's all that matters right now :) Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `singup` function doesn't return anything hence why you get the `error` either use `return` keyword before fetch or remove `{}`around your function